# How LuisIntent attribute is overriden?

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

```
[LuisIntent(intentName: "Eligibility")]
private async Task Eligibility(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
   await context.PostAsync($"You have chosen the eligibility intent with no entities");
  context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

How to override LuisIntent attribute such that it takes both IntentName and EntityName??

Comment: You want to have 2 different methods for 1 intent and 2 entities?

Comment: Unlike attributes in general, the LuisAttribute is not `sealed`, so you can subclass it - but the framework won't know that you have done that, and won't pass the entity to it.

Comment: .. and anyway, you already get the entities in the `LuisResult` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you want to do can be done in a simpler way assuming that what you want to do is to execute a different logic depending if an entity (or more than one) was detected.

The `LuisResult` class that you get in the intent method contains an `Entities` property with the list of entities that `LUIS` detected based on your query.

If you still want to do the filtering overriding things, then I believe that you will have to start by overriding the `DispatchToIntentHandler` method of the [LuisDialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/LuisDialog.cs). That method is the one responsible for looking in the intent handlers dictionary , based on the intent name,  which handler need storage be called.

However, that won't be likely enough and you will have to create a new `EnumerateHandlers` because as I mentioned before, the dictionary of handlers is being created just with the intent name as the key and it seems you want to incorporate entities.

Finally, you will have to update the `LuisIntentAttribute` to incorporate the Entity name you want to filter.

As you can see the overriding path is not the best way to go.